# How can I make my blog working in html5. there is no db or sql involved

Tags: html, comments, blogs

I am trying to build a blog with my html5 webiste. I have created the form for comment but I have no idea how can I make user to post comment to that post. i have comment and likes counter fixed as I do not know what to do.

```
 <!-- Comment Form ============================================= //-->
                                            <div id="respond" class="respond clearfix">
                                                <h3 class="comment-respond-title">Leave a <span class="comment">Comment</span></h3>
                                                <form id="appointment-form" action="#" method="post" class="appointment-form clearfix">
                                                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control">
                                                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                                        <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control">
                                                        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                                        <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control">
                                                        <label for="phone">Address</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                                        <textarea id="textarea" rows="4" class="form-control form-textarea"></textarea>
                                                        <label for="textarea">Textarea</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="btn-wrapper">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-make-app">Submit comment </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the form data on the webserver using whatever server-side language suits you best. For simple sites like this the simplest choice would be PHP. Read through the available docs at http://php.net/, that site has excellent documentation.

Comment: Do you have any idea where can I find any starter files?

Comment: Did you already try writing a PHP script to process your form data yourself? There are probably code examples on the internet that mostly do what you need, have you googled for such examples? I won't do the searching for you...